# Separating Parsing Method

Tags: java, parsing, file-io

I'm creating a program which handles SKU's. I currently have two classes in my program, the `SKU` class is the main class and a `Store` class in which an `ArrayList` is initialised and `SKU` objects are stored in the array. I currently have a method in my `SKU` class which takes input from a file, parses the data and stores the data using a `String` tokenizer in the objects variables and adds the objects to the array in the `Store` class. The problem I'm facing is that I'm wanting to separate the parsing method in the `SKU` class so that it simply reads from a line, and then have a separate method which takes a file input for the parser and finally update my `Store` class so that it initialises the products with the parsed data. Please, can you help me in regards to this?

My parsing method in the `SKU` class is currently as follows:

```
public void parser() {
    try {
    // create a Buffered Reader object instance with a FileReader
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("products.txt"));

        // read from first line from the text file
        String fileRead = br.readLine();
        // skip first line from sample file as it contains headings
        int lineNumber = 0;

        // loop until all lines are read
        while (fileRead != null)
        {
             if(lineNumber == 0) {
                        lineNumber++;
                        continue;
                    }

                    lineNumber++;

            // use string.split to load a string array with the values from each line of
            // the file, using a tab as the delimiter
            String[] tokenize = fileRead.split("\t");

            // assume file is made correctly
            // and make temporary variables for the three types of data
            String tempProductCode = tokenize[0];
            String tempDescription = tokenize[1];
            BigDecimal tempPrice = new BigDecimal(tokenize[2]);

            // create temporary instance of SKU object
            // and load with three data values
            SKU tempObj = new SKU();
            tempObj.setProductCode(tempProductCode);
            tempObj.setDescription(tempDescription);
            tempObj.setPrice(tempPrice);

            // add to array list
            Store.mySkuArrayList.add(tempObj);

            // read next line before looping
            // if end of file reached 
            fileRead = br.readLine();
        }

        // close file stream
        br.close();
}

    // handle exceptions
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
    {
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }

    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My `Store` class is as follows:

```
public class Store {
public static ArrayList<SKU> mySkuArrayList = new ArrayList<SKU>();

public void addSKU(SKU sku) {
    mySkuArrayList.add(sku);
}
```

Comment: This sounds more like a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to refactor your code.

Answer (score 1):

Split your code to three separate classes. SkuFile class represents text file where sku codes is stored, this class knows how to every sku entry stored and able to parse it. Sku class contains data. Store class contains 
list of Sku and accept SkuFile in it's constructor.

```
class SkuFile {
    private String path;

    SkuFile(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }


    List<Sku> readAllSku() {
        ArrayList<Sku> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File(path).toPath());
            for(String skuLine : lines) {
                result.add(parseFrom(skuLine));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private Sku parseFrom(String data){
        String[] tokenize = data.split("\t");
        productCode = tokenize[0];
        description = tokenize[1];
        price = new BigDecimal(tokenize[2]);
        return new Sku(productCode, description, price);
    }
}

class Sku {
    private String code;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;

    Sku(String code, String description, BigDecimal price) {
        this.code = code;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;   
    }

    //getters setters methods
}


class Store {
    private List<Sku> skus;

    Store(SkuFile file) {
        skus = file.readAllSku();
    }
}


class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Store store = new Store(new SkuFile("products.txt"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is by making the parse method return a **list of tokenizers**(e.g. List tokenizeList) and a second method which takes that list as input and populates the *SkuArrayList*

Possible implementation of the parser method

```
public List<String[]> parser() {
    List<String[]> tokenizeList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ... /*file opening logic*/
        while (fileRead != null)
        {
            .../*line counting logic*/
            String[] tokenize = fileRead.split("\t");
            tokenizeList.add(tokenize);

            fileRead = br.readLine();
        }

        // close file stream
        br.close();
    }// handle exceptions
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
    {
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tokenizeList;
}
```

Possible implementation of the populate store method

```
public void populateStore(List<String[]> tokenizeList) {
    for(String[] tokenize: tokenizeList) {
         String tempProductCode = tokenize[0];
         String tempDescription = tokenize[1];
         BigDecimal tempPrice = new BigDecimal(tokenize[2]);

         SKU tempObj = new SKU();
         tempObj.setProductCode(tempProductCode);
         tempObj.setDescription(tempDescription);
         tempObj.setPrice(tempPrice);

         // add to array list
         Store.mySkuArrayList.add(tempObj);
    }
}
```

And the main method from where you call these two methods

```
public void foo() {
    populateStore(parser());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, did you mean to pass the 'parser' method to the parameter for the populateStore method in the call under the main method?

Comment: Maybe main was not the best name for that method( I renamed it to foo). And yes, I wanted to pass the result from the parser method to the populateStore method. Another way you could do that is to store the result of the parser in a variable and pass that variable to the other method.